# How to run pod file in iOS directory in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at projects\reactNative\ios\Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?
(node:11696) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error Could not get the simulator list from Xcode. Please open Xcode and try running project directly from there to resolve the remaining issues. Run CLI with --verbose flag

Answer (score 3):

## Issue 1

For fixing the issue:

> Could not find "Podfile.lock" at projects\reactNative\ios\Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?

Please make sure you have install cocoapods and run this command at your project root:

```
gem install cocoapods           // If you haven't install cocoapods
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

---

## Issue 2

For fixing the issue:

> (node:11696) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency (Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)

Please downgrade your node.js version to v13.x.x, one of the solutions below:

```
npm install -g n
sudo n 13.13.0
```

---

## Issue 3

For fixing the issue:

> Could not get the simulator list from Xcode. Please open Xcode and try running project directly from there to resolve the remaining issues. Run CLI with --verbose flag

Please make sure you have installed Xcode correctly from App Store and use the latest `React Native` version in your project (should be `v0.62.2` now for stable). If still cannot open the project, please try to add some simulator in Xcode's `developer settings`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you did not install cocoapods

install cocoapods commands

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

after that in react native directory

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ../ && react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `CocoaPods` manages library dependencies for your Xcode projects. We need it to setup the iOS project. Like `yarn`

```
    sudo gem install cocoapods
```

2. The `Podfile` is a specification that describes the dependencies of the targets of one or more Xcode projects. Like `package.json`
3. access to the folder with `Podfile`, run

```
 pod install
```

This will resolve the code of those dependency framework, and generate `Pods.xcodeproj` for your iOS project.